# On click, search for bookmark and display the div the bookmark is in

Tags: jquery

Is this possible with jQuery or some other method? Basically, I have a bookmark hyperlink in a div that is displaying on the screen. It links to a bookmark tag in another div that isn't being displayed. Is it possible, when the user clicks the bookmark link, to detect the properties of the div containing the bookmark and set that div display to show?

```
<div class="cpecontent" id="content_2">
  <h2><br />
    <a name="0.1__Toc320283140"> </a> <a name="0.1__Toc325358918"> </a>Determine All Sources of Income (Taxable and Non-Taxable)</h2>
  <p><br />
    Reaching into the bag you pull out an amorphous jumble of paper. There are receipts, a stapled stack of credit card statements, a few 1099s, a W-2, a manila envelope labeled "investments," some check stubs, and one artificial fingernail. "What is all this?" you inquire. </p>
  <p><br />
    "Monday nights at 6:15. It's all about the lottery and I play a woman who runs this magical machine that grabs numbered ping pong balls. It's like a big popcorn machine. My character presses a button that makes the machine grab a ball out of the air. When the machine grabs a ball, she has to turn it so the number faces the camera. There's no dialogue yet, but my manager says they're probably going to expand my role." </p>
  <p><br />
    <!--ON Click for this Bookmark, set the div below to display:show;-->
    <a href="#0.1__Gross_Income" title="_Gross_Income"> <span> For more on this topics - see Appendix A </a> </p>
</div>


<!--A LOT OF CONTENT IN BETWEEN-->

<!--This DIV is hidden right now, but we want to try and show it-->
<div class="cpecontent" id="content_11" style="display:none;">
  <h2><br />
    <a name="0.1__Toc325358937"> </a> <a name="0.1__Gross_Income"> </a>Gross Income</h2>
  <p><br />
    All of the following constitute possible sources of Gross Income:</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;line-height:12pt">Wages</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;line-height:12pt">Self-employment income</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;line-height:12pt">Partnership and S corporation income</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    $('a[name="'+this.href.replace('#', '')+'"]').show();
});
```

BTW I think those links are called anchors not bookmarks.

Comment: How does this code set the div to show? You found the bookmark, but then is it possible to detect the div that the bookmark is in and show that div?

Comment: this.href is coming across with the entire URL, for example, 'http://domain.com/index-page-continuing-professional-education-subpage-display-course-27.htm#0.1__Gross_Income. Is there a way to split the string on #?

Comment: I just found out that links also have a hash property.
`this.hash.replace('#', '')`

Comment: Also, if your links don't **start** with '#' you'll have to use the contains selector `$('a[href*="#"]')`